# .NET core 6 throws arithmetic overflow exception when using lambda

Tags: .net-core

Why only lambda version of `miniMaxSum` function throws an Arithmetic overflow exception?

Code with Lambda:

```cs
void miniMaxSum(List<int> arr)
{
    Int64 maxNum = 0;
    Int64 minNum = 0;
    Int64 min = 0;
    Int64 max = 0;
    maxNum = arr.Max();
    minNum = arr.Min();
    min = arr.Where(n => n != maxNum).Sum();
    max = arr.Where(n => n != minNum).Sum();
        
    Console.WriteLine($"{min} {max}");
}

List<int> nums = new List<int>{
    256741038, 
    623958417, 
    467905213, 
    714532089, 
    938071625
};

miniMaxSum(nums);
```

**Output:**

> Unhandled exception. System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable`1 source)   at Program.<<Main>$>g__miniMaxSum|0_0(List`1 arr) in /home/gabriel/source/HackerRank/MinMaxSum/Program.cs:line 10

code without Lambda:

```cs
void miniMaxSum(List<int> arr)
{
    Int64 maxNum = 0;
    Int64 minNum = 0;
    Int64 min = 0;
    Int64 max = 0;
    maxNum = arr.Max();
    minNum = arr.Min();
    Int64 aux = 0;
    for (int i =0;i <arr.Count;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != maxNum)
        {
            aux = checked((Int64)(min=min+arr[i]));
            min = aux;
        }
            
        if (arr[i] != minNum)
        {
            aux = checked((Int64)(max=max+arr[i]));
            max = aux;
        }
    }
         
    Console.WriteLine($"{min} {max}");
}

List<int> nums = new List<int>{
    256741038, 
    623958417, 
    467905213, 
    714532089, 
    938071625
};

miniMaxSum(nums);
```

**Output:**

> 2063136757 2744467344

Anyone can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linq [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-sum(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-int32)))) method returns the same type that you are applying it to, in this case an `int`, just because you are assigning it to a `long`/`Int64` doesn't change that, hence it will overflow. One way to fix that is to convert the list items to `long`, you can do that using a `Select`:

```
min = arr
    .Where(n => n != maxNum)
    .Select(x => (long)x)
    .Sum();

max = arr
    .Where(n => n != minNum)
    .Select(x => (long)x)
    .Sum();
```